# Using preprocessor definition in additional include directories

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, macros, c-preprocessor

I have defined a

**LIBDIR = $(ProjectDir)..\lib**

in Project Properties -> C++ -> Preprocesor, which seems to be evaluated correctly.

Now, I want to add an include directory in C++ -> General -> Additional Library Directories which uses the definition above. Something like:

**LIBDIR\include**

This one is being evaluated incorrectly.

Any hints?

I am using Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Visual Studio 2015

Comment: @PaulR, that's correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot define new build macros in Visual Studio. Thus, to define the additional library directory you can only use the predefined macros, like ***$(ProjectDir)..\lib\inlcude***

The preprocessor definition you've defined in the first step used solely in source files.

Comment: Thanks for the precise answer.